# Symfony2 Doctrine Array of joined objects

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have the following repository:

```
class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function searchCustomer($criteria)
    {
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $q->join('TeamERPCustomerBundle:Company', 'o', 
                    'WITH', 'c.company = o.id');
    if (isset($criteria) and $criteria!=""){
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.customer_name like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
    (...)
    }
        $q = $q->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        return $q;
    }
}
```

I call it from the controller as follows:

```
            $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                ->getRepository('TeamERPCustomerBundle:Customer')
                ->searchCustomer($customerInfo);
```

It returns an array of elements as follows:

```
array (size=20)
  0 => 
array (size=9)
  'id' => int 1
  'customer_name' => string 'Abel' (length=4)
  'address' => string 'Calle 52 # 60, % 3era y G. Quezada, Nuevo Sosa' (length=46)
  'postal_address' => string '75100' (length=5)
  'city_town_village' => string 'Las Tunas' (length=9)
  'e_mail' => string 'abel@ltu.sld.cu' (length=15)
  'land_line' => string '346386' (length=6)
  'cell_phone' => null
  'fax' => null
  1 => 
array (size=2)
  'id' => int 1
  'company_name' => string 'Debswana' (length=8)
  2 => 
array (size=9)
  'id' => int 2
  'customer_name' => string 'Kay' (length=3)
  'address' => null
  'postal_address' => null
  'city_town_village' => null
  'e_mail' => null
  'land_line' => null
  'cell_phone' => null
  'fax' => null
  3 => 
array (size=2)
  'id' => int 3
  'company_name' => string 'DTC' (length=3)
(...)
```

It gives one element of the array per object, but what I want it the classic mysql join; as result an array of elements of the same type. Something like mergin elements 1 and 2 together.

The other problem with this query is that is does not work like that classic join ether, it gives all the customers, but only the companies that are not repeated.

Can anyone help me to get a uniform array of elements?

**Edit: I managed to find a solution:**

```
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT c, i
        FROM TeamERPCustomerBundle:Customer c
        JOIN c.company i');

    //$query->setParameter('id', '1'); With this is can add as many parameter as I need

    return $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

This returned something like this:

```
array (size=11)
  0 => 
array (size=10)
  'id' => int 1
  'customer_name' => string 'Abel' (length=4)
  'address' => string 'Calle 52 # 60, % 3era y G. Quezada, Nuevo Sosa' (length=46)
  'postal_address' => string '75100' (length=5)
  'city_town_village' => string 'Las Tunas' (length=9)
  'e_mail' => string 'abel@ltu.sld.cu' (length=15)
  'land_line' => string '346386' (length=6)
  'cell_phone' => null
  'fax' => null
  'company' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'company_name' => string 'Debswana' (length=8)
```

As you might have already appreciated this array is different from what I was getting before. so now I just have to go through the array and change it to what ever I want. for instance:

```
           foreach ($result as $key => $value){
               $result[$key]['company'] = $value['company']['company_name'];
           }
```

Now we are talking. This Is kind of what I wanted:

```
array (size=11)
  0 => 
array (size=10)
  'id' => int 1
  'customer_name' => string 'Abel' (length=4)
  'address' => string 'Calle 52 # 60, % 3era y G. Quezada, Nuevo Sosa' (length=46)
  'postal_address' => string '75100' (length=5)
  'city_town_village' => string 'Las Tunas' (length=9)
  'e_mail' => string 'abel@ltu.sld.cu' (length=15)
  'land_line' => string '346386' (length=6)
  'cell_phone' => null
  'fax' => null
  'company' => string 'Debswana' (length=8)
```